# Rails > Upload image via email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a rails plugin or gem out there that allows users to upload their image by emailing the image as an email attachment?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the fetching code from [here](http://railspikes.com/2007/6/1/rails-email-processing) and then just use ActionMailer.receive to create an object from it/load the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [mail](http://github.com/mikel/mail) which lets you create and read/parse emails.